# Error 400 when pushing tx hex to mempool.space's API

Tags: transactions, api, raw-transaction, mempool.space

I am using the code syntax provided by mempool.space for a POST transaction request from their website here:

https://mempool.space/api

```
const mempoolJS = require("@mempool/mempool.js")

const init = async () => {
  
  const { bitcoin: { transactions } } = mempoolJS({
    hostname: 'mempool.space'
  });

  const txHex = '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';

  const txid = await transactions.postTx({ txHex });
  console.log(txid);
          
};
init();
```

This code snippet isn't working for me. I keep getting a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 400`. I am unsure if it's because I am using the require instead of import? Or I am not correctly sending a POST request? Or not handling the Promise syntax correctly?

Would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Try this: https://pastebin.com/raw/3DL7ULsW

Comment: Would I be entering all this into the same .js file?

Comment: I will share the steps for this workaround in answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code and apparently the code is right but your Hex string is wrong.
The API response is as follows:

`data: 'sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-22,"message":"TX decode failed. Make sure the tx has at least one input."}'`

Make sure that you have right Hex to post your tx. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a transaction and get hex:

```
0200000000010119335721e24061cab07c9caf3a9ed331b85511af3d6be38ef37bda93ddce49880100000000fdffffff02a086010000000000160014243588dda3d0560986069a55b386c1d3417ecc2e19a903000000000016001469577cafbaa617f64cd468ff51a578aeb85cfcf202473044022066c1314f71f05cf1c2e27298dc056d7b66cbc2bab0b3d536ad084fa577d9a0650220349102e2d151309b7820ff848d39ba28c6763f972e90359300dbfd3131ff4fa1012102cc2868604a6db586db0d72654f71835a3d6c20e465eea4597509963f47bd3c65dbe91f00
```

2. Use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) to send a POST request with:

   URL: https://mempool.space/testnet/api/tx

   Body: Transaction hex
3. It will return transaction id:

[`23b0c4ce54e13a846e6a9f50f11019071f98c53f1d82ea9c674de1c7a94af45a`](https://mempool.space/testnet/tx/23b0c4ce54e13a846e6a9f50f11019071f98c53f1d82ea9c674de1c7a94af45a)

[image: postman]

Doing same thing using JavaScript:

1. Click on `</>`

[image: postman-code]

2. Select one of the options for JavaScript. I used JavaScript-Fetch:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");

var raw = "020000000001015af44aa9c7e14d679cea821d3fc5981f071910f1509f6a6e843ae154cec4b0230100000000fdffffff02a0860100000000001600141c97aee9cf15d8a9016c3a98c5a503ed49d012caec2102000000000016001463924d833ecc676de6dec0cf6c72c6c94bc1c5350247304402206fbb992ce8f8e35b5c229dae731709c7d82de404d882e62271ce6e7551e103ff02203e94d589766db4e583d862b6ad3951fe62c498b11fdeae85bfc37ef61e2af13a0121039072d28be7d83a8f4b1983da7a74d2bd28e80ee79d4ee2bf603e101865099378dce91f00";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://mempool.space/testnet/api/tx", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

3. Run this on https://jsfiddle.net/ and you will get the transaction id in response:

[image: fiddle]

[`bd0306a1fa6e262949c9856ebcea61c0857067e1d2c856d0216a9cf871e4a377`](https://mempool.space/testnet/tx/bd0306a1fa6e262949c9856ebcea61c0857067e1d2c856d0216a9cf871e4a377)

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. Except I had to tweak the top line to this:

```
var myHeaders = new fetch.Headers()
```

Also, I got an error back from their server saying:
```
sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-25,"message":"bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent"}
```

But I am sure there is an input already specified in my raw tx hex. I'll share the hex below.

Comment: 0200000001661f29d4f3a3ccedf3865b51ade356715f8b201c6c1299c0ab64ba502d4ae274000000006a4730440220516e15b6354f17e3f02711107624005e6ccd26cf61ef21b35e91315dfbd33e9f022049dadb73ca3e814de9da0b35ff20a8ca82147dda138ede948ccac5621a5bc1bb01210384485d43e938f8c68c4ac903d4d5a97fe842f66c12b860d8d2e1242d2b01fc1fffffffff0160ea00000000000016001490638c5df76b1a37dc852e21ed5be5b66dbe199100000000

Comment: There is something wrong with the transaction. Maybe some inputs already spent.

Comment: actually the reason was because i was signing it incorrectly. But its all fixed now. Thanks again.